# int foo(int grade, void* factor) - How can the factor be used inside the function?

Tags: c, c99

I have a situation where the `factor` variable can be **a pointer** to an `int` or a `float`, the function's signature must look as it looks below:

```
int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor) {
    return (grade * (*factor));
}
```

What's wrong with the dereferencing of `factor`? I assumed factor is a pointer as it is of `void *` type, so I've used `(*factor)` to dereference it before using it.

What am I missing here? Why's GCC yelling at me?

```
ex_3.c: In function `calcFactor':
ex_3.c:51:19: warning: dereferencing `void *' pointer [enabled by default]
  return (grade * (*factor));
                   ^
ex_3.c:51:2: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  return (grade * (*factor));
  ^
```

Comment: You are missing the type information. Except for polymorphic types (in C++ only, not C), the type information is not inherently available at runtime without your applying some effort. You need to cast `factor` to either `int*` or `float*`. For example: `int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor, _Bool is_int) { if (is_int) return grade * (int*) factor; else return grade * (float*) factor; }`

Comment: You can't overload functions in C, and you can't fake it by passing a pointer to `void`. Make two functions.

Comment: @EOF, that's an exercise for a course in the University. I guess I didn't get the instructions right.

Comment: Can you post the exact assignment? Maybe we can make sense of it.

Comment: @EOF, I appreciate it, but the English of the professor assistant is very broken and I'm afraid it'll take me about an hour to translate it to proper English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Float(x) (x << 1)
#define Int(x) (x << 1) + 1
//or  use the least significant bit from that pointer of int and float is an even address    
int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor);

int main(){
    int factor_i = 10;
    float factor_f = 0.5;
    printf("%d\n", calcFactor(Float(85), (void*)&factor_f));
    printf("%d\n", calcFactor(Int(85), (void*)&factor_i));
    return 0;
}

int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor) {
    return (grade >> 1) * (grade & 1 ?  *(int*)factor : *(float*)factor);
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define INT 1

int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor);

int main(){
    int factor_i = 10;
    float factor_f = 0.5;
    printf("%d\n", calcFactor(85, (void*)&factor_f));
    printf("%d\n", calcFactor(85, (void*)((uintptr_t)&factor_i | INT)));
    return 0;
}

int calcFactor(int grade, void *factor) {
    return grade * ((uintptr_t)factor & INT ?  *(int*)((uintptr_t)factor ^ INT) : *(float*)factor);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're insane or a genius.

Comment: we can not change the function prototype of calcFactor, so we need to have the information to either argument.

Comment: Yes... Let's go with that. I will warn about signed shift though.

Comment: woha man, that's sick. a true overkill for the given assignment but I've learned so much from your code.

Comment: the negative value is used for grade was not considered, but it seems to be able to use those pointers.;D

Comment: I shudder at your blatant abuse of alignment restrictions. Bravo! (But the C standard would condemn you to hell for it.)

Comment: Standard probably will not complain. Of course, the environment and the range that can be used is limited. Though as another proposal,  that use the global variable...XD

Answer (score 1):

you need convert the value factor point to before the value can be multiple to another value
try

```
return (grade * (*(int *)factor);
```

Comment: OP wants a function that works for both ints and floats.  Unfortunately, straight C doesn't have RTTI so I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I feel you, I haven't written in C for a long long time. I guess I must have some information before using the function.

Comment: @Kevin is right, for the function itself, go for http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ in c++. No sure what does the assignment look like though.